# so how does passing by reference in php REALLY work?

Tags: php, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference, interpreter

Really simple question but rather than asking for an academic explanation I want to keep it as pragmatic as possible: when will PHP create a copy of my huge class I'm passing into a function and when will it simply create a pointer to the relevant data? And if it creates pointers all the time, what's the use of specifying & (aside from closures, obviously)? I guess I don't know enough about the guts of the interpreter.

Comment: What's wrong  with this explanation ? http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatare.php

Comment: The only thing that's wrong with said explanation is apparently the intelligence level of its audience (me)

Comment: Try to avoid them in your code, as this feature would be deprecated in newer versions of PHP

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP architecture, and pass-by-reference vs pass-by-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392987/php-architecture-and-pass-by-reference-vs-pass-by-value)

Comment: @Mark Trapp -- if it's a possible duplicate, why don't you make sure of that yourself before spamming my post, thanks.

@Nazariy, thanks. That's more of what I'm after. I know it's been deprecated, so is there any reason really now to use & with my OBJECT that I'm passing in?

Comment: @kappasims It's customary to point out that it could be a duplicate question. He posted it here because he thinks the answer you want might be in it already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP 5, all objects are passed by their handle. Whether you pass by reference or not is irrelevant in terms of performance. (In fact, passing by reference is warned to be *slower* in the manual.) The object you are working on inside the function is the same object as pointed to outside the function.

When you pass an object (handle) by reference, then you can alter what the outer variable points to. This is almost always unnecessary.

Comment: Just to be clear, I am speaking only of objects. PHP does pass a copy of all other data types (strings, etc). However, the copy only actually happens if you modify the data. So again, references are not usually "faster." Their real purpose is when you need to modify what the variable in the calling scope actually points to. So I would generally avoid using them unless you need that specific behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The `&` operator denotes a variable as being passed by reference.

```
$x = 'Hello World';
echo($x);

function asdf(&$var){
  $var = 'Test';
}

asdf($x);
echo($x);
```

Same goes for assignment and pretty much any other statement. If it isn't passed or assigned by reference, assume it is passed or assigned by value instead.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I am more interested not so much in whether or not the value will be changed but whether or not I will take an efficiency hit by that object being duplicated. Going off of the link posted earlier, I am wondering if this really makes a huge difference as PHP is "copy on write"

Comment: Use `microtime()` to test how long it takes for an object to be duplicated versus how long it takes for an object to be passed by reference. I don't really think it makes a large difference, at least the amount of time it takes has been negligible for the smaller objects I have created. The bigger problem is more about functionality rather than execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with &, even though you can do so as please. This is how I do:

Assume I have a class 'Book' with some public methods and properties like title, author, year
then to make an object of it simply:

```
$book = new Book()
// then I can use all public methods and properties

$book->title;

$book->author;

$book->year;
```

If I like to then I can make a subclass say

```
class Novel extends Books{

  function buildIt(Book $bk){

      $bk->title;

      // so on 

  }

}
```

In the function buildIt, I purposedly have an class object of Book 'parameter' in which
I can pass the whole object of class 'Book'.

I hope this help.

Comment: Sure, I guess that my question is that when you are referencing $bk->title, is that copied to a new temporary Book with a whole new $title in memory that can be changed with no effect on the original Book object, and if that's the case, is that bad for performance to duplicate the object?

Comment: Objects are passed-by-reference by default, this is why it is meaningless in your examples. When passing primitive data types though (e.g.: integer, string, etc.), this is where it comes in handy.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot of uses of passing a variable by reference in the PHP manual. One of the best examples is [preg_match](http://php.net/preg_match).

`preg_match` will return the number of occurrences a pattern has been matched in the input string. It will then populate, if provided, a referenced `$matches` array containing the matches.

It can be seen as a way to return more than one value, although you ought to be careful with that. Per example:

```
class Server {

    protected $_clientId = 0;

    protected $_clients = array();

    /**
     * Get a pending connection.
     *
     * @param &$connection_id int The connection identifier.
     * @return resource The socket resource.
     */
    public function getNextClient(&$connection_id) {
        $clientSocket = socket_accept($this->_server);     
        $connection_id = $this->_clientId++; 
        $this->_clients[$connection_id] = $clientSocket;
        return $clientSocket;
    }

}

$server = new Server;
$socket1 = $server->getNextClient($id);
echo $id; // 0
$socket2 = $server->getNextClient($id);
echo $id; // 1
```

Important note. Objects are passed-by-reference by default. **They will not be cloned**. Even without specifying the `&` in the function argument, modifying the passed object will result in the original object being modified as well. The only way to prevent this is to clone the object in the function/method.